# CALayer move few times in animation

Tags: objective-c, animation, calayer

Now I have animation - move calayer from actual point to other , one move:

```
CGPoint startPt = CGPointMake(self.firstBall.ballCoordinates.x,self.firstBall.ballCoordinates.y);
 CGPoint endPt = CGPointMake(self.secondBall.ballCoordinates.x,self.secondBall.ballCoordinates.y);

 CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
 anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
 anim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:startPt];
 anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPt];
 anim.repeatCount = 0;
 anim.duration = 1.0;
 [self.firstBall.ballLayer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position"];
```

How can I create animation when my calayer move few time from one point to other in one animation ?

Comment: Do you simply want to repeat the animation (make it happen many times)? I'm having trouble understanding what you seeking for.

Comment: No no, I want to my Calayer move few time when every point is other. It should looks like my calayer walks in path ;)

Comment: Sorry, I just don't understand what you mean by "move few time when every point is other". Do you mean that is should jump in small bursts instead of being a continuos animation?

Comment: Now I do move from point (x1,y1) to point (x2,y2) because CABasicAnimation have only property from and to. How to move my calayer in path:(x1,y1) to (x2,y2) to (x3,y3) to (x4,y4) ? Do You understand ?

Comment: You are looking for CAKeyframeAnimation.